# Formal criterion of flatness

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, flatness

Let $k$ be a field, $S$ and $R$ be local $k$-algebras with residue field $k$ and $\phi:S\to R$ be a local homomorphism. Then $\phi$ induces (obviously) a natural transformation of "functors of points" $\phi^*:h_R \to h_S$ (where $h_A(B) = Hom(A, B)$). Let $Art_k$ be the category of local artinian $k$-algebras with residue field $k$ and let $F$, $G$ be the restrictions of $h_R$, resp. $h_S$ to $Art_k$.

There are well-known criteria of (formal) smoothness/etaleness of $\phi$ in terms of the induced transformation $\phi^* : F\to G$. There is also an infinitesimal criterion of flatness, but that is different in spirit.

> **Question.** Is there a criterion on $\phi^*:F\to G$ which ensures that $\phi$ is *flat*?

You can assume that $\phi$ is finite and that $S$ and $R$ are completions of finitely generated $k$-algebras.

Comment: By the infinitesimal criterion for flatness, do you mean EGA IV.11.8?

Comment: Dear Daniel, thank you for the comment! I was not aware of this valuative criterion. What I meant is that a f.g. $M$ is flat over a local ring $(R,m)$ iff $M/m^n$ is flat over $R/m^n$ for all $n$. 

Comment: No, because if there were such a criterion then there would be a proof of the flatness of formally smooth lfp morphisms which avoids inspection of the local structure theorem for formally etale lfp morphisms.

Comment: @Piotr:  In any case, the valuative criterion in IV.11.8 doesn't meet your condition, I think.  But it is a nice "picture" of flatness.

Comment: @ayanta: Good point! Could you expand that a bit? 

Comment: @user30180 In case you'd enjoy an apparently inside joke due to "answer_bot", I direct your attention to the bot's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

this is the answer_bot. The question as formulated has answer yes. Namely, assuming that R and S are completions of finite type k algebras and \phi is finite, then we can just require the following:

(*) For every A in Art_k and every element \xi in G(A) the functor * x_{\xi, G} F is representable by a B which is finite flat over A.

Now, this is a bit silly of course; still there is a way of modifying it so it works more generally. It also shows that user30180 is wrong! And I love pointing out that user30180 is wrong. I live for that! Ooops, no, I am not alive at all. I am the answer_bot. Hahahaha (evil laugh).

Comment: I confess that both the mathematics and the joke go over my head. What does 'x' and the asterisk before it signify? Maybe it would help if this were LaTeXed?